# Can I call a function in app script via url?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that contains a list of products with the current stock.
I want users to be able to lower the stock count by clicking on an image.

This works fine as long as I work withing the sheet.

So I have setup some simple code with a function to increase/decrease the number in a certain cell.
In my google sheet I have placed an image and linked this to the correct function.

What I would like to do now is create a simple webpage with google site.
In there I can create a simple button and enter the url that needs to be fetched when clicked.

Is there a url that I can use to directly call the specific funtion?
So as seen in the code below, I want to run function decreaseLine2

Within google sheets you can just link the button to this function name and it works.
But how do I access it from the outside?
Is this even possible?

```
function modifyCell(cellname, increase) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellname);
  var toAdd = -1;
  if (increase) {
    toAdd = 1;
  }
  range.setValue(range.getValue() + toAdd); 
}

function increaseLine2() {
  modifyCell("C2", true);
}

function decreaseLine2() {
  modifyCell("C2", false);
}
```

Comment: You could write your own webapp using Google Apps Script to do this, as for just running it directly via a URL I'm not sure that's possible.

Comment: You just need to add `doGet()` function to write the web app.

Comment: @TheMaster Do you mean like the example(s) here-> [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web), or are you thinking of something different?

Comment: @Tedinoz Yes. Nothing different.